# Enlarge pictures in image-dired

Tags: image-dired

When I use the `image-dired` but find pictures displays in very small size.
[image]

How could enlarge them?

Answer (score 1):

You can select the picture in the `*image-dired*` buffer and press `+` to increase the size of the selected picture.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the thumbnails size, you can set the variable `image-dired-thumb-size`. For example:

```
(setq image-dired-thumb-size 80)
```